# Are there more Turing-unrecognizable languages than recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines, church-turing-thesis

Say you generated a language by looking at the output of a lexicographic enumerator and flipping a coin for each string, adding it to the language on heads. What would be the chance of this language being Turing-recognizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact one can show that there are uncountably many languages (say by representing a language as a sequence of the form $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb N$ which can be interpreted as the binary form of some real number in $[0, 1]$) while there are only countably many TMs (as any TM can be represented by a finite string), so almost all languages are undecidable, i.e. assuming we draw a language from an uniform distribution the probability of it being decidable would be 0.

Comment: I presume the chance of it being recognizable would also be 0 then?

Comment: Yes, this follows as well as every TM recognizes one language.